# Where do I find the Outlook 2007 Data Files?

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-outlook, livecd

I'm repairing a computer for a friend, the computer won't boot into Windows (Vista) and I've tried all of the usual stuff (BIOS settings, repair console etc) so I'm in with a Ubuntu Live CD backing everything up before I do a clean install. Long story short, I'm trying to find the Outlook data files, I want to make sure I get the right ones and I get them all.

My questions are:

- How many files are there?
- What are they called?
- Where are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook` 
Messages: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`

Source: http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/config/backup-config/outlook-2007-backup-and-dual-boot-file-locations/#.TrVVvrxAB4o